# vba: get the week day number from a date?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the week day number from a date.

E.g. :  if it is a Monday returns 1, if it is a Tuesday it returns 2, ... if it is a Sunday it returns 7.

I was wondering if there is a direct function to obtain this, for instance:

```
DayNumber = Format(Date, <format unknown to me>)
```

The closest I could get is to use the function:

```
DayNumber = Format(Date, "dddd")
```

then loop through a predefined list of possible names, but I still wonder if there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of googling would have found the `WEEKDAY` function

`weekday(date,vbMonday)`

Comment: Hello, weekday is indeed working, though I am a bit disappointed by the unnecessary comment: my Google searches did not lead me there, neither did searches on stack overflow. I would wish I would get more empathy toward my own search.

Comment: Apologies "Find weekday in excel vba" gave me 10,400,000 results in under 1/2 a second, the first being WEEKDAY